# Send file from Android Kotlin to C# using POST

Tags: c#, android, file-upload

We have two applications: A C# REST-API, and a Kotlin Android application, we are using  Google Platform Cloud Bucket to host the images.

A picture will be uploaded on the Android application, but the C# REST-API needs to upload it to the Google Cloud Platform.

This is the working C# code to upload a file to the Google Cloud Buckets:

```cs
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("upload")]
        public IActionResult Upload()
        {
            var storageClient = StorageClient.Create(google_credentials);

            string fileToUpload ="/Users/niel/Downloads/new_cat.jpg";
            
            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(fileToUpload, FileMode.Open,
                FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
            {
                storageClient.UploadObject("test_storage_fotos", "new_cat", "image/jpeg", fileStream);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("uploaded the file successfully");

            return Ok();
        }
```

Now I need to replace `fileToUpload` with the content from a POST-request. Is there a way to do this? Picture from Android app > C# API > Google Buckets? The link from the C# API to Google Buckets is already working.

Is there a way in Kotlin to somehow get the byte-string of an image, post it to my C# API who takes the content and puts it in a `FileStream`? I than can upload the `FileStream` using `storageClient.UploadObject`? Is this a possibility?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use Retrofit in Android to send any file, also, you should have an Endpoint to receive files from Android.

Comment: But I don't want to actually have the endpoint to save the file. I want to send the content of the file to the server, and than the server passes it on to Google Buckets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can definitely do this. Just send the file over to the server via **http** protocol with **multipart/form-data** content type.

In kotlin you can use **ktor** or any other http library to do that.
For ktor you'll need to add an implementation dependency

```
implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-android:1.5.4"
```

And you might also need to add additional permission in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Then you can send a file with this snippet. Notice that imageUri is a content uri, for file uri the code would be a bit different

```
private fun getFileName(resolver: ContentResolver, uri: Uri): String {
    val returnCursor: Cursor = resolver.query(uri, null, null, null, null)!!
    val nameIndex: Int = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME)
    returnCursor.moveToFirst()
    val name: String = returnCursor.getString(nameIndex)
    returnCursor.close()
    return name
}

suspend fun postAndImage(imageUri: Uri, uploadEndPoint: String) {
    val client = HttpClient(Android)

    val cr = applicationContext.contentResolver
    if(cr.getType(imageUri) == null) {
        //process error
        return
    }

    val stream = cr.openInputStream(imageUri)

    if(stream == null) {
        //process error
        return
    }

    val response: HttpResponse = client.submitFormWithBinaryData(
        url = uploadEndPoint,
        formData = formData {
            append("image", InputProvider { stream.asInput() }, Headers.build {
                append(HttpHeaders.ContentType, cr.getType(imageUri)!!)
                append(HttpHeaders.ContentDisposition, "filename=${getFileName(cr, imageUri)}")
            })
        }
    )

    stream.close()

    //process response
}
```

And you'll need to modify you upload function slightly

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("upload")]
//the name of the argument must match the key that you pass in "append" function
public async Task<IActionResult> Post(IFormFile image)
{            
    var storageClient = StorageClient.Create(google_credentials);

    using (var stream = image.OpenReadStream())
    {           
        //it's also possible to get original file name from file name property
        var fileName = Guid.NewGuid() + "." + Path.GetExtension(image.FileName);
            
        //assuming bucket is already created
        var storageObject = await storageClient
                    .UploadObjectAsync("test_storage_fotos", fileName, "image/jpeg", stream);
        //save information about a storage object in database
    }

    return Ok();
}
```